# Program closes after running twice

Tags: c++

A lot of code, so its a bit of tall order to read through. Thanks if you're willing to spend the time!

To explain what I made, its a program that converts certain units of measurement into other units of measurement. The user picks which unit they wish to convert and how much of that unit.

Once the program runs, the user is sent back to the main options menu where they can close the program, or continue with another conversion.

However, my issue is this, the program runs fine and everything works EXCEPT it stops after two iterations. If the user converts something, then converts again, the program ends, when it should continue until the user selects the option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int answer, subAnswer;

void printIntro();
double mainMenu();
void printOutro();
double length();
double weight();
double volume();
double area();
void printAnswer(double, string, double, string);

// for length conversions
double inches, yards, miles;
double cm, ms, km;

// for weight conversions
double ounces, pounds, tons;
double grams, kGrams;

// for volume conversions
double pints, quarts, gallons;
double liters;

// for area conversions
double sq_milo, sq_meters;
double sq_inches, sq_feet, acres;

int main()
{
    printIntro();
    mainMenu();
    printOutro();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printIntro()
{
    cout << "\tWelcome to the Unit Conversion helper." << endl;
    cout << "\nPick from the following menu to get started." << endl;
    cout << "Example: Type '1' to select length conversions.\n" << endl;
}

double mainMenu()
{
    cout << "***************************************************\n";
    cout << "1. Lengths\n";
    cout << "2. Weights\n";
    cout << "3. Volumes\n";
    cout << "4. Areas\n";
    cout << "5. Quit program\n";
    cout << "***************************************************" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        length();
    }

    if (answer == 2)
    {
        weight();
    }

    if (answer == 3)
    {
        volume();
    }

    if (answer == 4)
    {
        area();
    }

    if (answer == 5)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}

double length()
{
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to convert?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Convert Inches to centimeters." << endl;
    cout << "2. Convert Yards to meters." << endl;
    cout << "3. Convert Miles to kilometers.\n" << endl;
    cin >> subAnswer;

    if (subAnswer == 1)
    {
        cout << "How many inches?\n" << endl;
        cin >> inches;

        cm = inches * 2.54;
        printAnswer(inches, " Inches is equal to ", cm, " Centimeters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 2)
    {
        cout << "How many yards?\n" << endl;
        cin >> yards;

        ms = yards * 0.9144;
        printAnswer(yards, " Yards is equal to ", ms, " Meters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 3)
    {
        cout << "How many miles?\n" << endl;
        cin >> miles;

        km = miles * 1.609344;
        printAnswer(miles, " Miles is equal to ", km, " Kilometers.\n");
    }

    return cm, ms, km;
}

double weight()
{
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to convert?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Convert Ounces to grams." << endl;
    cout << "2. Convert Pounds to kilograms." << endl;
    cout << "3. Convert Tons to kilograms.\n" << endl;
    cin >> subAnswer;

    if (subAnswer == 1)
    {
        cout << "How many ounces?\n" << endl;
        cin >> ounces;

        grams = ounces * 28.349523;
        printAnswer(ounces, " Ounces is equal to ", grams, " Grams.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 2)
    {
        cout << "How many pounds?\n" << endl;
        cin >> pounds;

        kGrams = pounds * 0.453592;
        printAnswer(pounds, " Pounds is equal to ", kGrams, " Kilograms.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 3)
    {
        cout << "How many tons?\n" << endl;
        cin >> tons;

        kGrams = tons * 907.18474;
        printAnswer(tons, " Tons is equal to ", kGrams, " Kilograms.\n");
    }

    return grams, kGrams;
}

double volume()
{
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to convert?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Convert pints to liters." << endl;
    cout << "2. Convert quarts to liters." << endl;
    cout << "3. Convert gallons to liters.\n" << endl;
    cin >> subAnswer;

    if (subAnswer == 1)
    {
        cout << "How many pints?\n" << endl;
        cin >> pints;

        liters = pints * 0.4731631;
        printAnswer(pints, " Pints is equal to ", liters, " Liters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 2)
    {
        cout << "How many quarts?\n" << endl;
        cin >> quarts;

        liters = quarts * 0.946326;
        printAnswer(quarts, " Quarts is equal to ", liters, " Liters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 3)
    {
        cout << "How many gallons?\n" << endl;
        cin >> gallons;

        liters = gallons * 3.785306;
        printAnswer(gallons, " Gallons is equal to ", liters, " Liters.\n");
    }

    return liters;
}

double area()
{
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to convert?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Convert square inches to square millimeters." << endl;
    cout << "2. Convert square feet to square meters." << endl;
    cout << "3. Convert acres to square meters.\n" << endl;
    cin >> subAnswer;

    if (subAnswer == 1)
    {
        cout << "How many square inches?\n" << endl;
        cin >> sq_inches;

        sq_milo = sq_inches * 645.16;
        printAnswer(sq_inches, " Square Inches is equal to ", sq_milo,
            " Square Millimeters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 2)
    {
        cout << "How many square feet?\n" << endl;
        cin >> sq_feet;

        sq_meters = sq_feet * 0.09290304;
        printAnswer(sq_feet, " Square feet is equal to ", sq_meters,
            " Square Meters.\n");
    }

    if (subAnswer == 3)
    {
        cout << "How many acres?\n" << endl;
        cin >> acres;

        sq_meters = acres * 4046.86;
        printAnswer(acres, " Acres is equal to ", sq_meters,
            " Square Meters.\n");
    }

    return sq_milo, sq_meters;
}

void printOutro()
{
    cout << "Returning to the main menu. If you're done, type 5.\n" << endl;
    cout << mainMenu();
}

void printAnswer(double cTemp, string sTemp, double dTemp, string rTemp)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << cTemp << sTemp << dTemp << rTemp << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your main menu as follows:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printIntro();
        mainMenu();
        printOutro();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And get rid of `cout << mainMenu();` in printOutro()

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: @Esteban Also do consider what others pointed out. There seems to be few bad practices in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First thing:

```
double length()
{
    ...
    ...
    return cm, ms, km;
}
```

This always return km, other ones will not be returned.

And there is bad logic:

```
printIntro();
mainMenu();
printOutro();
```

Program closes after runing twice, because you write it in that way. Look at above lines. You print intro, next print main menu, and execute what user want, and after that you print outro. Outro is calling main menu once more. And after that program has been closed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.